# How can I exclude workspace-external files from Quick Open in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On Vs Code while pressing Ctrl + P i can see history of different directory files included along with current working directory files.

I want to exclude out side files, When i open search files i want to only see current working directory files.

Please check below image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/STxzb.png

How i can configure it outside directory.

"search.useIgnoreFiles": false